# SOLVED: Prevent Sprite from being tilted when collide?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicscontact

How can I prevent two sprite nodes from being tilted when colliding. Let say I have a long rectangle with PhysicsBody 1 and a short rectangle with PhysicsBody 2. I want these 2 to hit, but don't want the long rectangle to be tilted after colliding but still standing straight. How can I achieve that?
This is the code for the long rectangle:

```
thePlayer.position = CGPoint(x: 100 - self.frame.size.width/2, y: 100 - self.frame.size.height/2)
thePlayer.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
thePlayer.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = gamePhysics.Player
thePlayer.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = gamePhysics.Wall
thePlayer.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = gamePhysics.Wall
thePlayer.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
thePlayer.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

This is the code for the short rectangle:

```
tileNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
tileNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: tileSize, center: CGPoint(x: tileSize.width / 2.0, y: tileSize.height / 2.0))
tileNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = gamePhysics.Wall
tileNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = gamePhysics.Player
tileNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = gamePhysics.Player
tileNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
```

Comment: Not sure this would work, but can you try setting `node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false`

Comment: Oh yes so simple! Thanks New Dev!

Answer (score 0):

As New Dev mention, the solution is simple. I added node.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false and it works.